# How to change Label format in Violin plot of Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting some data in the violin plot I want to keep the label format the same for all plots.
This below is the first plot:

[image]

I want the following given plot with the same formatted y-axis. (I want to add a scientific notation to the figure given below.) I want the exponential part common.
I searched a lot but could not get the solution. Please Help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add the scientific notation, you can use [`plt.ticklabel_format()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format.html)

Consider the following sample data and initial violin plot.

```
x = sorted([1,2,3,4,5] * 200)
y = (list(np.linspace(0.3 * 1e-3, 3 * 1e-4, 70)) + [0] * 130) * 2 + \
    list(np.linspace(0 * 1e-3, 1 * 1e-4, 200)) + \
    list(np.linspace(0 * 1e-3, 1.3 * 1e-4, 200)) * 2

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})

sns.violinplot(x='x',y='y',data=df)
```

[image]

By using [`plt.ticklabel_format()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format.html) the code and result will look like this:

```
sns.violinplot(x='x',y='y',data=df)

plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(3,10))
```

[image]

Comment: HI thanks for reply but i want just opposite. I want the figure given below as above.

Comment: I don't want to remove the scientific notation from the above figure instead I want to add a scientific notation to the lower figure.

Comment: My bad, sorry for misunderstanding the question. Just updated my answer to add scientific notation.

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved the problem.  :)